# How to prevent access to a directory (apache and nginx) in php

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a script with a subdirectory containing files that should not be accessible from outside (so, users cannot directly access it even if they know the remote URL).

In order to do so, I thought about programmatically creating a .htaccess file in the directory with the line

```
Deny from all
```

This would work, but I need this to work both on `apache` and `nginx`, and I am not very familiar with the latter. I wasn't able to find any good pieces of information on this, though, although as far as I understood I should NOT use .htaccess with `nginx`.

So my question is whether there is an alternative that would work on `nginx`. I did find out how to configure `nginx` to deny access to a specific folder, but I need the script to be able to do this by creating the local file. I can't assume to have access elsewhere to the server.

By the way, any other solution that does not involve .htaccess would be ok as well, as long as it prevents the direct access to the file through URL and it makes it accessible to php.
In case it matters, the script is part of a WordPress plugin.

Comment: nginx does not support .htaccess files and does not have an equivalent native mechanism to override the config per directory. The generally accepted way to prevent unwanted access to files is to put them outside the web server's document root directory.

Comment: is there a blank `index.php` in that subdirectory?

Comment: Spartacus, no, why? I could add it if it matters